# MD5sum is not calculated correctly

Tags: java, md5, message-digest

I am trying to match the md5sum of a downloaded file from server.
Processing will be continued only if sums match.

```
try {
      MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      File f = new File(fileName);
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);              
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      int read = 0;
      while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
      } 
      is.close();
      byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
      BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
      output = bigInt.toString(16);
      System.out.println("MD5: " + output);
  } catch(IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Above code doesn't provide the md5sum properly for some files every time.

When i go to console and check `md5sum <filename>` md5sum is same as that in server. But when same is calculated from code it is yielding a different result.

vimdiff of downloaded file is not providing any diff.. The files are proper after download.

I am unable to see a problem in above code.

I am trying to change the buffer size. But no luck, So i am guessing that it is not because of the buffer size etc.

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
```

Regards
Dheeraj Joshi

Comment: Anybody can look at the code and tell me if anything is wrong?

Comment: How about posting some actual and expected results?

Comment: what i have is 8611c0b0832bce5a19ceee626a403a7                 Expected  08611c0b0832bce5a19ceee626a403a7

Comment: I am changing BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
      output = bigInt.toString(16); to output = new String(Hex.encodeHex(md5sum));

Comment: Did it escape your notice that the expected value is the same as the actual value with a leading '0'? and is 32 digits long? so all you have to do is pad with leading zeros to 32 digits?

Comment: It did work when i change the method to output = new String(Hex.encodeHex(md5sum));

Comment: Couple of MD5's starts with 0 But Using bigInt yield 31 character string which i overlooked earlier.

Comment: I am guessing it is considering the leading 0 as sign bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger.toString method will escape the leading 0's as they are not important.

[BigInteger.toString method is deleting leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275769/biginteger-tostring-method-is-deleting-leading-0)