# BigInteger.toString method is deleting leading 0

Tags: java, tostring, biginteger

I am trying to generate MD5 sum using MessageDigest.
And i am having following code.

```
byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
output = bigInt.toString(16);
```

This returns not 32 character string but a 31 character string `8611c0b0832bce5a19ceee626a403a7`

Expected String is `08611c0b0832bce5a19ceee626a403a7`

Leading 0 is missing in the output.

I tried the other method

```
byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
output = new String(Hex.encodeHex(md5sum));
```

And the output is as expected.

I checked the doc and Integer.toString does the conversion according to it

> The digit-to-character mapping provided by Character.forDigit is
>   used, and a minus sign is prepended if appropriate.

and in Character.forDigit methos

> The digit argument is valid if 0 <=digit < radix.

Can some one tell me how two methods are different and why leading 0 is deleted?

Comment: Are you saying that `BigInteger.toString()` is *supposed* to output a leading zero?

Comment: All i am asking is why toString is removing the leading 0. ?

Comment: Yeah well and i get a negative vote as if it is not useful. Boohoo

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. How is `toString` supposed to know that you're expecting a leading 0? `BigInteger` stores just a number; it doesn't know how many leading zeroes you're expecting.

Comment: Think of it another way: what would you expect from `new BigInteger("27").toString()`? How many leading zeros?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would personally *avoid* using `BigInteger` to convert binary data to text. That's not really what it's there for, even if it *can* be used for that. There's loads of code available to convert a `byte[]` to its hex representation - e.g. using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or a simple single method:

```
private static final char[] HEX_DIGITS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String toHex(byte[] data) {
    char[] chars = new char[data.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        chars[i * 2] = HEX_DIGITS[(data[i] >> 4) & 0xf];
        chars[i * 2 + 1] = HEX_DIGITS[data[i] & 0xf];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> String.format("%064X", new BigInteger(1,
> ByteArray);

where

1. 0 - zero leading sign
2. 64 - string length
3. X - Uppercase
4. ByteArray - The ByteArray on which you want to run this operation

Comment: @Andro it's link to Cipher.getInstance("HMAC");

Answer (score 9):

It's deleted because the leading zero is not significant, according to `BigInteger`. There is no difference between `27` and `000000000027`.

If you want a specific length, you'll have to force it yourself, with something like:

```
output = ("00000000000000000000000000000000"+output).substring(output.length());
```

(kludgy though that is).

Answer (score 2):

The deleted zero is replaced using this code:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.reset();
digest.update(output.getBytes());
byte[] outDigest = digest.digest();
BigInteger outBigInt = new BigInteger(1,outDigest);
output = outBigInt.toString(16);
    while (output.length() < 32){
    output = "0"+output;
    }
```

loop will account for as many leading zeros as needed

Comment: I think Dheeraj was looking for reasons for the deleted zero.  Not a way to get it back.  Also, your code does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but my code does work sending the correct md5 checksum to my server.

Answer (score -2):

```
MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(PlainText.getBytes(),0,PlainText.length());
String M1=new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16);      
return M1;
```

Comment: Downvoted because your answer is not correctly formatted and it does not contain any explanations whatsoever.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting, but you still need to explain the code. Somebody [flagged your answer for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18790340), but [code-only answers are not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Your answer appears to be an attempt to answer the question, so should not have been flagged. Does it deserve a downvote? Quite possibly - I can't comment on its correctness or usefulness - but I personally have not downvoted.