# How to convert only the integer part of a BigDecimal to hex string?

Tags: java, hex, bigdecimal

I have a number of type BigDecimal, for example 18446744073709551616, and I want to convert it to hexadecimal value. I'm fine with truncating the fractional portion.

Is there a way to do this instead of doing it manually?

Comment: refer cource code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigDecimal.java.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Judging by your example you should use `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimal`. This way you could use

```
new BigInteger("18446744073709551616").toString(16)
```

If you can't change type of original object convert it to BigInteger later in method

```
new BigDecimal("18446744073709551616").toBigInteger().toString(16);
```

Comment: but for toString method it converts for example "16" to "10" not F as it should be in HEX representation.
is there anything to get the correct one ?

Comment: @becks it is correct result. Hex `F` is dec `15`. Take a look `a=10`, `b=11`, `c=12`, `d=13`, `e=14`, `f=15`. So decimal `16` would be `10` hexadecimal.

Comment: I get this, but is there a method to convert it automatically to letters representation instead of 10 11 to 15 ?
or I do it manually ?

Comment: @becks What do you mean? It converts dec to hex correctly (with `a,b,c,d,e,f`) `new BigInteger("30").toString(16)` returns `"1e"` which is expected result.

Comment: since **16** * `1` + **1** * `e` = 16 + 14 = 30.

Comment: I tried it for the value in my post but it converted it to 10000000000000000 instead of  FFFFFFFFFFFFFF80  
Is this expected ?

Comment: @becks why do you think `18446744073709551616` is `FFFFFFFFFFFFFF80`?

Comment: sorry guys, I miss calculated it. 

Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Comment: This will remove leading zeros

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev Remember that purpose of BigInteger is to hold *very* big numbers which `int` or `long` can't hold. How many leading zeroes would you expect and why?

Comment: I try to use it for MD5 and SHA1 hash sums, and if result should be starting with 0 then .toString(16) will remove leading zero

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev in that case you are probably looking for solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186197/converting-hex-to-binary-with-leading-zeros (although I would use `replace(' ','0')` instead of `replace(" ","0")` for possible performance increase). If I am not mistaken BigInteger can't simply assume amount of needed leading zeroes since it isn't type with predefined size like int (32 bits) or long (64 bits). It could be nice to have method like `toString(radix, predefinedSize)` to handle cases like yours, but I am not aware of any of these in standard Java.

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev This answer of Jon Skeet may also interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275845

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that converting a decimal value into hex requires an exponent. You could get the hexadecimal String representing a numeric value using [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

> %A : The result is formatted as a hexadecimal floating-point number with a significand and an exponent
> %X: The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer

Use the `%A` conversion if you want to convert a decimal value:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%A", myBigDecimal));
```

Curiously, the code above is correct regarding the javadoc for `Formatter`, but there seems to be a related *9-year-old* error in the javadocs, that has been fixed *a few weeks ago* in Java 8: [5035569 : (fmt) assertion error in Formatter for BigDecimal and %a](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5035569). You can use the analog code below:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%A", myBigDecimal.doubleValue()));
```

**EDIT**
Judging by the value in your post, you don't really care about the fractional part. You could use the `%X` conversion in the pattern and just provide the `BigInteger` representation:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("18446744073709551616");
System.out.println(String.format("%X", bd.toBigInteger()));
```

Comment: I get this error for the first one -- java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: a != java.math.BigDecimal
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)

Comment: Yes, it's strange and might be related to a bug: [5035569 : (fmt) assertion error in Formatter for BigDecimal and %a](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5035569) (the javadoc for `Formatter` states it's possible to convert a `BigDecimal`). Use the form below, using `doubleValue()` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I used doublevalue for the above value in the code but the result was
0X1.0P64 instead of 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80
is this expected ?

Comment: I am getting java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: a != java.math.BigDecimal for String.format("%A", new BigDecimal("1.1")

Comment: There's an error in the javadocs. It turns out `%A` doesn't accept `BigDecimal`. Pass in `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is possible to represent BigDecimal as a hex string, simiolar to Double.toHexString

```
0x1.199999999999p+1
```

but AFAIK there is no standard way to do it and custom implementation will not be easy

Comment: It is possible with `Formatter` and the `%A` conversion flag, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15616261/851811).